# High end supercharged LS2 will not accept throttle and is now missing on one bank

Tags: engine, electrical, chevrolet

Fully blueprinted all high end internals, cast iron LSX, supercharged and professionally dyno tuned. Engine has been performing flawlessly, (8,000 miles) owner is 65 years old, out of no where it began to fall flat upon serious acceleration, fuel pressure is perfect, leak down revealed nothing, injectors tested and good, throttle body is new. Spark plugs on one bank are all sooty, not gas soaked, other side is fine. Performance has deteriorated now to where engine is missing, tests show power to both banks, I will truly appreciate some educated input.
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You say "tests show power to both banks" ... what tests and what was the measured outcome?

Comment: Also, what are you using for the ignition? Just a stock ECM with the tune?